# SignalR to prevent gateway timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We have an ASP.Net MVC app that is running with a gateway policy that any web requests that go over 5 minutes are terminated. One of the features is exporting some data. It's been running just above 5 minutes. Would SignalR help? Does having a persistent connection between the client and server be enough for the gateway to think that it is active and will not terminate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We face the same issue in our project where we have to process some data in API and UI can't wait for such long processing time interval response from API.
We use SignalR to notify the requester UI/Client when data get successfully processed.